# Laravel error with correct key lenghts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I was working with laravel (5.4), everything fine. I cannot remember modifying my .env file but the following error came up in every page:

```
(1/1) RuntimeException
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

I tried every possible answer found on github.
This we're the steps i made:

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
Application key [...] set successfully.

php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!

php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!

php artisan cache:clear
Cache cleared successfully.
```

Also trying config:cache and then config:clear.
No results, error persists.

Comment: Can you once verify using `cat .env`?

Comment: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xxxxx....
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

etc...@BishnuBhusal

Answer (score 0):

did you try to put

> 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

in your config/app.php ?